# Why does XmlWriter.Create have output parameters?

Tags: .net

Why does XmlWriter's create methods have output parameters?

For example (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162619(v=vs.100).aspx))

```
public static XmlWriter Create(
    StringBuilder output,
    XmlWriterSettings settings
)

output 
  Type: System.Text.StringBuilder 
  The StringBuilder to which to write to.
  Content written by the XmlWriter is appended to the StringBuilder.
```

Why doesn't create not take the StringBuilder and instead of `Flush` have `toString` or `toStream` or `toStringBuilder` if thats whats really wanted.

I'm not asking how to use XmlWriter, I'm trying to understand the reasoning why it was constructed this way. I assume there is a reason, or even it to be a known pattern with advantages and disadvantages, I'd like to know more about this

Comment: That's not an "output" parameter (even though it's called "output"); it's just a reference to a StringBuilder.

Comment: It's not an `out` parameter, but MS name it output as when `Flush` is called the generated xml is appended to that StringBuilder. MS naming not mine!

Comment: `Flush` doesn't flush the entire thing; it just flushes the tail end.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an "output" parameter (even though it's called "output"); it's just a reference to a `StringBuilder`.

> Why doesn't create not take the StringBuilder and instead of Flush have toString or toStream or toStringBuilder if thats whats really wanted.

Because it uses the `StringBuilder` during the writing process.

Comment: Ah so it does the writing to StringBuilder during `WriteStartElement(String)` (for example) rather than at the end?

Comment: Yes, exactly...